# error_reporting(E_ALL) fails with no log or error message

Tags: php, error-handling, wordpress-rest-api

I am using the WordPress REST API and in my main plugin file I set:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I'm getting some weird behavior. For instance in a function/endpoint I have something like:

```
function test($request){
    $request['id'] <- this works fine here

    but if I add another function like this I get a silent error

    $validID = check_id($request['id']);
}
```

So when I do this my return from the endpoint is blank and I get this error:

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Now if I set error_reporting to:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

My endpoint works just fine. Not sure what is happening here. I don't get any php error logs and this makes it extremely difficult to troubleshoot. So should I just NOT use E_ALL?

I also tested the endpoint by leaving out a semi colon. I get the same result except now I get an empty response for both error_reporting(E_ALL) and error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE). I'd love to get some kind of log/return to tell me whats wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately a lot of WordPress code out there is written without `WP_DEBUG` enabled, which means without `E_ALL` level. As result it tends to be full of notices and deprecation issues developers don't see and don't bother to correct.

So raising error reporting can often trigger issues *entirely unrelated* to your own code.

Since your immediate problem is lack of obvious error message/log, you should experiment with `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` configuration to see if that helps.

Generally it's preferable to use constants to control WP's error handling centrally. When extensions start to mess with this it's... well, a mess. :)

Another thing you could try is a dedicated error handler. I made and use a [wps](https://github.com/Rarst/wps) plugin that wraps whoops handler for WP context. For API errors it tries to override the output and return a meaningful trace for what happened.